# How to send error message to form page from class

Tags: php, oop

I created a webform and validate it with php. I included the script file in the form page. So, I need to pass error message in an exact location of the form page to be visible for the user. Now I'm been able to display it only on top of the page echoing it in the script.

in the script file I defined my method in the class:

```
class CheckMail {

  public function responseMsg($responseTxt){
    return ($responseTxt);
  }

  public function checkFilename(){
    if (file_exists($filename)) {
      $this->responseMsg('Error! File already exists.');
    } else {
      $this->checkAttachment();
    }
  }

}
```

in the form page I need to display the error if it occours:

```
<?php echo responseMsg($responseTxt); ?>
<form> ... </form>
```

But I receive a Fatal error:

> Call to undefined function responsemsg()

My goal is to show the error in the form page, calling the method inside the class CheckMail.

Thx in advance for any help.

Comment: Are you using some form of MVC?  Your view (the form page) needs to have access to the same instantiation of the CheckMail object that initially checked the file name.  Your controller should at some point make that model available to your view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can not call class methods directly.

1- **How to call Static method.**

- The static method a is not tied to any particular instance of class.
  meaning it can be     called from anywhere with class reference (::).
  no need to create a object of class.
      https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.static.php

2- **How to call Non-Static method.**

- The non-static method is tied to a single instance of class. So you
  can not call Non-Static method without a specific class object.

**calling the method inside the class CheckMail.**

responseMsg is non-static method. to call this method you have need to create object of CheckMail.

```
//create object of class CheckMail
$CheckMail = new CheckMail ();
<?php echo  $CheckMail->responseMsg($responseTxt); ?>
```

Comment: ok, this is the right way to invoke the class and the method in it.